# How to return mutliple attributes from a webservice method

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

Iam creating a Java webservice following the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html). 
the method

```
@WebMethod
public String sayHello(String name) {
    return message + name + ".";
}
```

return one attribute, i want my soap request to contain more atrributes, how can i achieve this. Below is the sample of the soap response i want to get.

```
<soapenv:Body>
<processRequestResponse
  xmlns:ns2="http://..........">
 <return>
    <name>Phone</name>
    <value>25677xxxx</value>
 </return>
 <return>
    <name>Email</name>
    <value>sample@email.com</value>
  </return>
</processRequestResponse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then create a "wrapper" class which holds all the attributes you want to return, and change your web method to return an instance of that class, e.g.:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    // Add getters and setters.
}

@WebMethod
public Person getPerson(String someInputParam) {
    Person p = new Person();
    // Populate person
    return p;
}
```